# Porting designs from Illustrator to Figma (SVG)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, figma

I need to use some logos and other elements I've created on Illustrator in Figma. I know that you can save an entire project on Illustrator as SVG but how to pick certain elements, say shapes and logos etc. and just export those as SVG's? So not the whole project, just certain individual elements here and there.

Comment: This functionality is documented on the Adobe Help website here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/collect-assets-export-for-screens.html

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have a very old version of Illustrator, which doesn't have those functionalities.

Comment: Have you tried using copy and paste between the two apps? I don't use Figma, but in Sketch this would work.

Comment: Since you have an old version of Illustrator, it might be possible to copy and paste an object into a new blank document in Illustrator, then export the SVG. Delete the object, then do the same for the next object, export it with a different file name, and repeat until you have finished. It's a bit of a repetitive manual job, but it should get you there.

Comment: It's the same procedure if you have everything in AI as an AI file.. and need specific elements in their own file. SVG doesn't change anything. Am I missing something? Copy element, new document, paste, export, close.. repeat.

Comment: Simply take the shapes you need then take those on a separate artboard in illustrator and then make it for export as SVG. And then open that SVG file in Figma.

Answer (score 1):

You could create another artboard in the same project in illustrator and put the elements you need there, then export that artboard as SVG, open Figma and import as image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways:

The answer Kam gave works great, and I do that solution all the time. The only problem is if you have lots of different elements on the same artboard that you want saved separately, then you have to copy and paste, move them and form artboards for each of them. I personally do this a lot for bigger grouped objects.

Another way is to select the objects you want saved, go to File>Export Selection, and then choose SVG for the file format. You can change the format of the SVG in this window to whatever settings you want for figma.

Comment: The OP has a very old version of Illustrator. See comments under the question, so Export Selection won't work.

Comment: @BillyKerr Gotcha. I saw that it was an old version, but I didn’t know if it had export selection or not